# How to synchronize AI MinMax algorithm for checkers? Pseudocode

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, artificial-intelligence, minmax

I need to coordinate the MinMax method using threads. To make it clearer, I will not paste my MinMax.
*I use this algorithm to select the best possible moves for the computer in the game of checkers*

---

**This is pseudocode from Wikipedia:**

```
1 function minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer) is
2     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node then
3         return the heuristic value of node
4     if maximizingPlayer then
5         value := −∞
6         for each child of node do
7             value := max(value, minimax(child, depth − 1, FALSE))
8         return value
9     else (* minimizing player *)
10         value := +∞
11         for each child of node do
12             value := min(value, minimax(child, depth − 1, TRUE))
13         return value
```

---

```
var value = minimax(origin, depth, TRUE) // call
```

---

**I need to somehow implement threads into that method to make it faster.**

My knowledge of threads is really limited ... And I have to do it by tomorrow. Ultimately, I wrote the function in c#, but I will gladly take advice also in java, because I know it better than c#.

Could someone tell me where should I start?
I think I should call the method through a certain number of threads which would be based on the number of possible moves. Line 7 would probably be a good place? Recursion complicates things a lot and I get lost.
Should I somehow join these threads, or the recursion itself will force the whole method to work like this and not another.

---

Can anyone edit this pseudocode and show me some example of how I should start this specific number of threads. It can be in c# or java. Each piece of advice is worth its weight in gold. I know that the topic is extensive, but I tried to make it as specific as I can, so please the administrator did not close this topic to me :(

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Parallel.Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop). Keep in mind that scheduling work on a thread has some overhead, so just replacing the loops with the parallel equivalent will probably be much slower. A fairly simple approach would be to add a check for the depth and run it in parallel for the first level(s) and synchronous for the deeper levels.

Comment: What do you mean by `check for the depth and run it in parallel for the first level(s) and synchronous for the deeper levels`?

Comment: @brarord Add a check, `if (depth > SomeValue) {use parallel foreach} else {regular for each}`